# Oracle SQL Developer - node "tables" missing from navigation pane

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I must have done something to my configuration because my SQL Developer is missing the "tables" node in the lefthand navigation tree -- note the absence of "Tables" as very first item, between the DB connection node and "Views":
[image]

**Where in SQL Developer can a user configure what nodes are displayed?** I've tried googling for this but my keywords return a lot of irrelevant stuff so I might have missed if the answer was really there.

This is SQL Developer v4.0.

Comment: 4.0.WhatExactly?

I've seen this before, and it required a 're-install' to fix. I've not seen it happen in v4.0.3 or our 4.1 beta builds.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Funny to see you respond here :-D -- I came across your excellent blog and posted a comment today.  Anyway, this is on 4.0.3 and Mat has provided the correct solution already = I made a mistake.

Comment: Ha...well there was indeed a bug that would make JUST the tables node 'go away' - but I'm glad it was just your preference setting :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a way to selectively disable some items in there, but you can't really do that accidentally - your installation might have corrupted itself somehow.

To unhide the "Table" item, go to *Tools* -> *Preferences*. Then expand the *Database* item and select *Navigation Filter*. If *Tables* is unchecked there, check it.

[image]

You can disable the feature entirely from the same page (checkbox at the bottom of the UI).

Comment: YES! Thank you, I must have messed with this setting recently, but I couldn't find it again in the Prefs.